# Me aparece el siguiente error Reverse for 'agregar' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['carroagregar/(?P<producto_id>[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: python, django

A que se debe este error? no logro encontrar el error he estado haciendo el curso de pildoras indormaticas en youtube ta cual lo hace el profesor pero en el ultimo video me sale ese error y revise y tengo todo igual y no puedo hacer funcionar el codigo.

```
urls.py
from . import views
from django.urls import path

app_name="carro"

urlpatterns = [
        path('agregar/<int:producto_id>/', views.agregar_producto, name="agregar"),
        path('eliminar/<int:producto_id>/', views.eliminar_producto, name="eliminar"), 
        path('restar/<int:producto_id>/', views.restar_producto, name="restar"), 
        path('limpiar/', views.limpiar_carro, name="limpiar"), 
    ]

tienda.html

{% extends "ProyectoWebApp/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <div style="float:right;">
    <p>Total:{{importe_total_carro}}</p>
    {% include "carro/widget.html" %}
    <p>Total:{{product.precio__sum}}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      {% for producto in productos %}
        <div class="col-md-3" >
          <div class="card" style="width: 100%; margin: 5px 5px;">

            <img src="{{producto.imagen.url}}" class="card-img-top">
            <div class="card-body" style="text-align:center;">

              <h7 class="card-title">{{producto.nombre}}</h7>
              <p class="card-text">$&nbsp;{{producto.precio}}</p>
              
            </div>         
            <div class="card-footer text-center">
              <a href="{% url 'carro:agregar' producto_id %}" class="btn btn-success">Agregar al carro</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      
      {% endfor %}   

  </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import include, path


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin', admin.site.urls),
    path('servicios', include('servicios.urls')),
    path('tienda', include('tienda.urls')),
    path('contacto', include('contacto.urls')),
    path('blog', include('blog.urls')),
    path('carro', include('carro.urls')),
    path('', include('ProyectoWebApp.urls')),
    
]
```

La verdad no se cual puede ser el problema es como que las url del la app carro no existieran?? o eso creo que puede ser... la verdad he buscado y no encuentro el problema si se necesita alguna otra parte del código lo subo.

Comment: ya lo edite si necesitas mas codigo para poder ayudarme me avisas...estaria muy agradecido si puedes ayudarme con esto.

Comment: Lastimosamente no he trabajado con Django, vote a favor para que tengas la atención correspondiente

Comment: Muesta el urls.py a nivel proyecto.

Comment: ya agregue el url.py del proyecto

Answer (score 1):

Esta parte esta mal:

```
<div class="card-footer text-center">
          <a href="{% url 'carro:agregar' producto_id %}" class="btn btn-success">Agregar al carro</a>
        </div>
```

No es producto_id es producto.id.

Quedaria de esta manera

```
<div class="card-footer text-center">
          <a href="{% url 'carro:agregar' producto.id %}" class="btn btn-success">Agregar al carro</a>
        </div>
```

Me dices si se soluciona con este cambio

Answer (score 0):

Hola me sucedia lo mismo y encontré la solución la publico espero que les sirva porque lei que muchos tenian el mismo problema

En el URLS.PY de Carro yo lo tenia de la siguiente manera

```
path('agregar/<int:producto_id/', views.agregar_producto, name="agregar"),
path('eliminar/<int:producto_id/', views.eliminar_producto, name="eliminar"),
path('restar/<int:producto_id/', views.restar_producto, name="restar"),
path('limpiar/', views.limpiar_carro, name="limpiar"),
```

Lo que me pasaba era que en el <int: no lo volvia a cerrar con el signo de mayor, tambien cambie las comillas a simples

```
path('agregar/<int:producto_id>/', views.agregar_producto, name="agregar"),
path('eliminar/<int:producto_id>/', views.eliminar_producto, name="eliminar"),
path('restar/<int:producto_id>/', views.restar_producto, name="restar"),
path('limpiar/', views.limpiar_carro, name="limpiar"),
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, pero tu respuesta no coincide con la pregunta. Tu error era otro y no puede ser considerada una respuesta válida aunque esteis hablando del mismo tema, lo siento.  Por este motivo puede ser considerada de baja calidad y ser eliminada o recibir votos negativos.

Answer (score 0):

Otra posible solucion es revisar como estan recorriendo el ciclo for por ejemplo yo recorri el ciclo con la variable i entonces al pasar el parametro a la url deberia de poner i.id y no producto.id como lo hicieron el ejemplo aqui parte del codigo en el template tienda

```
   {% for i in productos %}
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="card" style="width:100%; margin: 5px 5px;">
    <img  src="{{i.imagen.url}}" class="card-img-top"  >
    <div class="card-body" style="text-align: center">
    <h7 class="card-title">{{i.nombre}}</h7>
    <p class="card-text">{{i.precio}}&nbsp$</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer text-center" style="resize:both; overflow:auto; font-size: calc(1em + 1vw)">

    <a href="{% url 'carro:agregar' i.id  %}" class="btn btn-success">Agregar al carro</a>

  </div>
  </div>
</div>
{%endfor%}
```

tambien revisar el archivo urls de carro para checar como estas construyendo la url por ejemplo puedes quitar en namespace carro y hacer la llamada directamente a la url agregar

Answer (score 0):

Me pasaba igual, el problema era que en el bucle `for` es: `{% for Producto in productos %}`
; pero en:
`<a href="{% url 'carro:agregar' producto.id %}" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" style="color: white"><strong>Agregar al Carro</strong></a>`.

La solución estuvo en escribir correctamente:

`<a href="{% url 'carro:agregar' Producto.id %}" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" style="color: white"><strong>Agregar al Carro</strong></a>`.

*Aquí la pinta no es lo de menos.*

Comment: Esto realmente no responde a la pregunta. Si tienes una pregunta diferente, la puedes formular haciendo clic en [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). También puedes [ofrecer una recompensa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) para atraer más atención a esta pregunta cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/344172)

Comment: ¡Elimina tu [otra respuesta](/a/544217)! Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score -1):

Me pasaba igual, el problema era que en el bucle for había escrito producto y no Producto. Como sabemos amigos, aqui la pinta no es lo de menos. Saludos.

Comment: Disculpas, esta es la primera vez que hago un aporte. Me pasaba igual, el problema era que en el bucle for decía:  {% for Producto in productos %},pero yo escribí mal en el enlace, habia puesto producto con minúscula. 

<a href="{% url 'carro:agregar' Producto.id %}" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" style="color: white"><strong>Agregar al Carro</strong></a>. Esta la manera correcta con lo que me funcionó.

Comment: Esto realmente no responde a la pregunta. Si tienes una pregunta diferente, la puedes formular haciendo clic en [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). También puedes [ofrecer una recompensa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) para atraer más atención a esta pregunta cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/344169)